# jQuery, Get filename without the extension and then replace string

Tags: jquery, regex, str-replace

I have this code to get the file extension:

```
filename1 = "a.crudely_formed.document_name.jpg"         
var fileExtension = filename1.substring(filename1.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Now I need to only get the filename, without the extension. As you can see in the example file names can be wildly named by the users, that's why I have to use the lastIndexOf() method.
I've searched for a method of doing this, but I found nothing.

Additionally, when I have the filename (without the extension) I need something similiar to this

```
$filename = strtolower(str_replace(array('  ', ' '), '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]/', '', trim($filename))));
```

Above basically means, replace all spaces with dashes and only allow a-z and A-Z characters and all numbers. In the example above for example åöä is replaced by aoa.

Any suggestions on how to do this in jQuery?

Comment: `filename = filename1.substring(0,filename1.lastIndexOf('.'));` ?

Comment: Thanks! Pushed me in the right direction. Any ideas on the second question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, to only get the filename I used this:

```
var output = filename1.substr(0, filename1.lastIndexOf('.')) || filename1;
```

To do the replacement of characters I used this:

```
output = output.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way to get filename and extension

> fileName = 'upload.png';

**If you need only filename**

```
filename.split('.').shift();
```

**If you need only extension**

```
filename.split('.').pop();
```

Comment: Your code fails when filename itself contains dot(.).

Comment: if that case, you can remove the extension and take left